# My app compiles, but crashes at run time - why?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
         --------- beginning of crash
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 1062
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Device Nexus_5X_API_25 [emulator-5554]disconnected, monitoring stopped.
Application terminated.

```
-----------------------Gradle Module file-------------


 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '28'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
`enter code here`'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    //compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6"

}
```

Comment: can you share build.gradle  file ?

Comment: Given in the question now

Comment: Also try `buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`.

Comment: Which version of AS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is version mismatch (Version should be same for both dependencies)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

And replace `compile` with `implementation` or `api`.

Hope it will fix it.

Comment: changing the services map api version to 9.4.0 , makes the build successful again.Thank you.